# Mat Table Pagination Not Working When Data length is less than 9 - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, paginator, mat-pagination

Im using mat pagination, it works correctly when the length is greater or equals than 10, but it breaks when the length is less than that.

Version angular: 13

[working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgYCj.png)

[broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuFgC.png)

my last try:

TS:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

this.paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel = 'Elementos por página';
this.paginator.length = res.length;
this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
this.paginator.pageSize = 25;
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

The HTML:
`<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>`

Comment: What do you mean by "broken"? What errors did you get? What is your expected result?